# Как получить список населенных пунктов из карты Яндекса — из определ. Зоны которую я создал?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit

Создал на сервисе Яндекс.Карты Зоны доставки.

Например:
[image: Зона 2]
Или
[image: Зона 3]

Каким образом можно вытащить список населенных пунктов находящихся в каждой из зон?
Именно названия требуются

Comment: Такой возможности нет. А задача-то какая в конечном счете?